# calling a new method in java from mxml produces "cannot invoke method" error

Tags: java, apache-flex

### UserService.java

```
...
        public class UserService {
                public static User getUser(String username, String password) {
                        ...
                }   

                public static User getUser2(String username, String password) {
                        ...
                }   
        }
```

### login.mxml

```
    private function loginUser() : void {
            lostPassword = false;

            // this works fine
        UserService.getUser(username.text, password.text);

            // this fails !
        UserService.getUser2(username.text, password.text);

        }
```

`getUser` was already in `UserService.java.`  I just created `getUser2` and it's identical to `getUser`.  When I try to call `getUser2`, i get the "`Cannot invoke method`" error.

question:  Do I need to specify getUser2 in some other file? like in some configuration file? if so, which one and how do I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you using JAVA-WS annotations?
2. Are you compiling the JAVA code?
3. Are you generating the service code via wsgen?
4. Are you using Flash Builder Data Services to introspect the service and generate client code?
5. If(4==true) Did you refresh the service?
6. Are you using BlazeDS remoting?

Comment: Is the timestamp on the version of `UserService.class` that's being loaded older than that on `UserService.java`?

Comment: @Kevin, sorry for the dumb question, but how to i compile java code in eclipse? do i have to download a java compiler for that.  @mike, i see UserService.java file but i don't see a separate file for UserService.class.

Answer (score 1):

think problem is JAVA static method according to [Remoting Service](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html) definition

*The [Remoting Service](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html) lets a client application access the **methods of server-side Java objects***

In **java/oops** static methods are not associated to Object/instance its depends-upon/associated to class

your method should be like this to accept call from flex

```
public class UserService {
                public User getUser(String username, String password) {
                        ...
                }   

                public User getUser2(String username, String password) {
                        ...
                }   
        }
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: I am using Flex to edit both the msml and java and the Export Release Build option to build the swf file. I then copy the swf file to our test server for testing.  The getUser has static declaration in front of it and it worked fine, but not for getUser2.  For testing purposes, I removed all the static declarations (for both getUser2 and getUser) and the problem still persists.  It can't be that difficult to work in flex !  Thanks in advance for all the help..

Comment: correction: I am using eclipse to edit the msml and java, then eclipse's Export Release Build option to build the swf file.

Comment: question: do i need to compile the java code (e.g. UserService.java) separately? if so, which tool should i used? thanks.

Comment: Are you using Flex builder?, it provides project type in which Flex & compiles and deployed together in WAR of BlazeDS

Comment: I finally figured it out.  There were 3 things I did wrong:
1) I needed to copy the compiled java class (UserService.class) to the deployment server, not just the Index.swf file.
2) The project had incorrect Content Root and paths
3) Website need a restart after each deployment (A quick and dirty shortcut is to simply make a smaller change to web.xml)
Learning java was actually a snap.  It's getting Flex setup and learning the nuances of deployment that took most of the time.
Thank you all for the help, especially Imran.  Mahalo :)